# Parts at the left side of a book

Tags: table-of-contents

i have to divide my book in parts that containing chapters. The parts don't have a name. I want to put the parts numeration at the left side of my toc. I post a picture for being more clear.[image]

Comment: That depends on the document you have so far. Please add a short compilable tex code you tried so far resulting in your issue ...